# Permission for all users to post to a specific feed

Tags: getstream-io

I have been attempting to implement stream via react native and seem to be struggling with what looks like a permissions issue in relation to all users being unable to post to another 'entities' feed.  My use case is essentially several 'topic' pages, where all users of my app can post to and comment etc. The topic page will also have an owner who can manage the page if needs be, so they too are essentially a 'user.

I've read elsewhere that global write permissions are not enabled by default so may need a member of the stream team to look at this for me if possible.

Here is the code I'm trying to use on the client side:

```
let user = client.feed('user', "bob");
let activity = {
  actor: "bob",
  verb: 'post',
  object: "Hello world",
  foreign_id: 'post:1',
  to: ['user:topic-page-1'],
};
user
  .addActivity(activity)
  .then(data => {
    console.log('success');
  })
  .catch(reason => {
    alert(reason);
  });
```

Another small issue I can't seem to get to the bottom of, is even when posting to the same user's timeline, the post username is always displaying as "Unknown" no matter what data I attach. What am I getting wrong here please?

Answer (score 1):

For the actor field to be treated as a user entity, you should use a reference, something like `client.currentUser` or `client.user('bob')`. This should fix your post username issue.